# Is it possible to obfuscate or encrypt Azure blob names?

Tags: azure, blob

My application stores uploaded user data to my Azure blob storage account - things like photos, for example. The blobs are named after their corresponding rows' primary keys in a relational database; for example `/tenants/12/users/456/photos/1563445`.

These files are meant to be accessible by anonymous, unauthenticated users, but I don't want to expose the primary-key values (to prevent "sequential access" attacks, or for my competitors to see how popular my service is).

Currently my blob storage container is private and all requests for blobs are proxied through my web application. To reduce server load I would like to expose the blobs directly, however this would mean exposing the raw blob name to end-users, which gives away the unencrypted database primary-key value.

I know I can prevent access to blobs using Shared Access Signatures however I don't need that kind of security - I just want to obfuscate blob names - such as through simple symmetric encryption.

Is there any way to achieve this using a "pure Azure" approach and directly exposing the blob store, or do I have to use my own proxy?

Comment: Is there an opportunity when you are uploading the file to hash the file name and then keep a reference in your db?

Comment: I see no reason why not to use SAS URLs. Not needing that level of security is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: Guids as names seem like a solution. Non sequential and what I heard it's very difficult to re-generate this same guid twice as long as the algorithm used to generate them uses NIC MAC address. It would mean that guessing an existing guid is even more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be completely up to you and your app. As long as container and blob names follow the published naming conventions, you can name them anything you want. But if you want to obfuscate what they really are (such as database id's), you'll need to do your own mapping, and store that map somewhere. There's no built-in obfuscation feature of blob storage.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is just hashids [hashids](http://hashids.org/)

However in general using a public container for user's private data is not a good idea. SAS is actually very secure because the link only available a while, before peopel hack into it, it's should already been expired.

Comment: This isn't the place to plug products. And the issue has nothing to do with SAS being good or bad, or about using public containers.

Comment: @DavidMakogon The author asked about obfuscate blob name, the hashids is clearly an answer for that. I don't think this is 'plug products', otherwise any technical term will be a 'plug products'.